# function working fine in IE but the same function is not working for mozilla 3.6

Tags: javascript, dom

```
function VisibleDiv(obj) {
if (obj == BaseLog) {
var objStyle = document.getElementById('DivCalls').style;
if (objStyle.display == "block")
objStyle.display = "none";
else
objStyle.display = "block";
}
else if (obj == ViewReports) {
var objStyle = document.getElementById('DivReports').style;
if (objStyle.display == "block")
objStyle.display = "none";
else
objStyle.display = "block";
}
else if (obj ==Management) {
var objStyle = document.getElementById('DivManage').style;
if (objStyle.display == "block")
objStyle.display = "none";
else
objStyle.display = "block";
}

<a href="#" id="BaseLog" class="TextHeader" onclick="VisibleDiv(this)">Base Log </a>
```

in the above code is working in IE but not working in mozilla 3.6.
I have checked that `obj==BaseLog` is not working in the above code.
I have tried many options like

```
event.srcelement
window.event.srcelement
```

but all in vain.
when I debug the code ,I found that obj is having complete value for IE but
the same obj is having all the names .ie. the name of tag,id and class for "Base Log" seperated by #. i.e `a#BaseLog#TextHeader#`
Please suggest what shoud I do?

Answer (score 6):

Either use

```
if (obj.id == 'BaseLog')
```

or

```
if (obj == getElementById('BaseLog'))
```

---

In IE, if an HTML element has `id` X, then in script the global variable X will be assigned to that element. This is not the case for many other browsers, which is also why it works in IE but not Firefox.